# What is the meaning of 日か

Tags: words

Full sentence:

マイケルの日かは、毎朝同僚全員に前日に見たアニメの感想を話すことです。

Michael's daily routine is to tell all of his colleagues his thoughts on the anime he watched on the previous day.

This sentence is from Wanikani and they often write things usually written in Kanji with Kana which could be the case here. Anyway, someone has an idea?

Comment: I would totally read this has ひ+か. If this was going to be 日課, this should either be in entirely kanji or entirely hiragana. Mixing it actually makes it less intuitive to read...

Answer (score 5):

The word is [日課【にっか】](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%97%A5%E8%AA%B2). The second kanji, 課, is a kyōiku kanji learned in the fourth grade of elementary school, and it's not difficult as compared to 僚. I don't know why this kanji alone is written in hiragana.

Comment: I looked up the sentence on WaniKani and 僚 was also in hiragana on there, so that apparent mismatch did not exist. They probably should just use furigana for kanji that haven't been taught yet, but they've always just used hiragana instead. It's particularly a problem in the older sentences on the site.